# Hotkeys-js - How can I unbind my Hotkeys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hotkeys

I am using `hotkeys-js` and bind `Enter` which triggers Submit function and close the Dialog. While closing, I try to unbind my hotkey, but my hotkey is continuously bound. I also tried to unbound like `handleHotkey: Function = event => hotkeys.unbind('Enter', this.handleHotKey) && this.handleSubmit()`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Basis extends Component {
  state = {
    open: true,
  }

  handleClose: Function = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false })
  }

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state

    return (
      <>
        {open && <Dialog onClose={this.handleClose}/>}
      </>
    )
  }
}


// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import hotkeys from 'hotkeys-js'

export default class Dialog extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    hotkeys('Enter', this.handleHotkeys)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    hotkeys.unbind('Enter', this.handleHotkeys)
  }

  handleHotkey: Function = event => this.handleSubmit()

  handleSubmit: Function = () => {
    console.log(12)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have to bind `this.handleHotkeys` correctly. Classic `this` scoping issue. Alternatively, have you tried just using `.unbind('enter');` ? Since you do not use the scopes, you can just unbind it globally and not worry about the correct reference to the function.

Comment: @Shilly If I unbind with `hotkeys.unbind('Enter')` also do not work.

Comment: Try setting the correct scope then. Since this is React with classes, try `this.handleHotkeys = this.handleHotkeys.bind(this);` inside the constructor to retain the this reference. ( same with this.handleSubmit ) That way you can pass it both to `hotkeys()` and `unbind()` as `this.handleHotkeys`. If you bind them locally, you end up with two functions instead of one. Or use more arrow functions.

Comment: @Shilly binding this function also do not work.

Comment: Good luck digging through the documentation. These two were the only ideas I have.

Comment: Thanks @Shilly. I already dig through the documentation like I know them by heart.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe component will not unmount. Try to unbind it it the onSubmit method

```
handleSubmit: Function = () => {
    console.log(12);
    hotkeys.unbind('Enter');
  }
```

But if you want to manage hotkeys after declaration it should be better to use setScope

```
setScope
Use the hotkeys.setScope method to set scope. There can only be one active scope besides 'all'. By default 'all' is always active.

// Define shortcuts with a scope
hotkeys('ctrl+o, ctrl+alt+enter', 'issues', function(){
  console.log('do something');
});
hotkeys('o, enter', 'files', function(){ 
  console.log('do something else');
});

// Set the scope (only 'all' and 'issues' shortcuts will be honored)
hotkeys.setScope('issues'); // default scope is 'all'
getScope
Use the hotkeys.getScope method to get scope.

hotkeys.getScope();
deleteScope
Use the hotkeys.deleteScope method to delete a scope. This will also remove all associated hotkeys with it.

hotkeys.deleteScope('issues');
```